# OnSwipeTouchListener and OnTouchListener doesn't work, when they're both in the code

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

I'm making an android-app where I have to click on a picture, but also swipe left/right. 
But when I have these two code snippets in my code at the same time, only OnSwipeTouchListener work. The listeners are both on the same ImageView.

Code 1:

```
     pic.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
            @Override
          public void onSwipeLeft() {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LEFT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
             public void onSwipeRight() {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "RIGHT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Code 2:

```
  pic.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CLICK WORKS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But when I have only "Code 2", the OnTouchListener code works perfectly.

How come?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what `OnSwipeTouchListener` is. But a view can only have only one `OnTouchListener`. Calling `pic.setOnTouchListener()` a second time also removes the first listener, so it's logical that both cannot be working at the same time.

What you want to do is create a single object that implements `View.OnTouchListener` and handles both swipes and single taps. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html for a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing a Viewpager with a ImageView fragment for this purpose. The swipe functionally is already integrated that way.